# php code to check if user is already logged in or not and then redirect

Tags: php, mysql

**table name - usermaster**
fields-- id,username,password,city

I have **two different department and their seprate webpage**.

I am **validating** 
**based on username ,password and city** and redirecting to their respective department page.

**Now I only  need to check if user is already logged in in any of this department,**

**and also try to login on another tab in same browser**

**then user redirect to their respective page other wise show login page.**

plz help me below is my login code..

```
 <?php 
      $usermaster = new usermaster;
      if(isset($_POST['login']))
      {         
            $city = make_safe($_POST['city']);
            $username = make_safe($_POST['username']);
            $password = $_POST['password'];         
            $result = $usermaster->select($usermaster->table,'',"username='$username' AND password='$password' AND city='$city'",'');       
            if(count($result))
            {        
               $_SESSION ['Auth']['id'] = $result['id'];        
               $_SESSION['Auth'] = $result[0];             
               unset($_SESSION['Auth']['password']);                  
               $_SESSION['city'] = $_REQUEST['city'];                  
              if($_SESSION['Auth']['department'] == 'Pagination')
              {
                 header ("Location: main.php");
                  exit;
              }
              else
              if($_SESSION['Auth']['department'] == 'CTP')
              {
                 header ("Location: ctp_final.php");
                  exit;
              }       
        }
              else
              { 
                $_SESSION['message1'] = "Wrong user Name or password";
                 header ("Location: index.php");    
                  exit;

              }          

      }
     ?>
```

Comment: Will you please tell that what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is when I am trying to login on same browser but in different department it logged in perfectly but reflect the session username same on both the department pages.but I enter diff. username and password for two different department login.

Comment: So you are trying to login to two separate accounts at the same time on the same browser? I don't think that will ever work. If you are simply trying to login to a new account then `session_destroy()` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: You have to first log out from one of them account and then have to do login. Without session_destroy(), you can't get other logged in user data. @Evilzebra is right.

Comment: yes i know this, but i am trying to open same page in which user is already logged in. when user try to login on another tab on another department or any other department.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not following your logic. Please clarify your question, maybe provide an example scenario.

Comment: for ex- if user is already logged in on pagination department...  and then also enter url on another tab to login on ctp department ...then it redirects automatically on pagination department.